# How to use Get-EventLog, Convert-ToHTML and add a javascript search box to filter entries?

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, event-log, event-viewer

### Edit: added a screenshot for Santiago of the HTML event viewer[image: HTML Event Viewer Sample]

To describe what I am trying to do. Note: in the meantime, I use ctrl f which is still way quicker than the Windows event viewer on a slow server.

1. I want to use PowerShell's Get-EventLog (done)
2. Convert the system event log into a nicely formatted HTML File (done)
3. Enable the ability to search the HTML generated EventLog data with a JavaScript
   search box that will essentially filter the data as you might with
   the filter functions in an Excel Spreadsheet (not yet working in
   Get-EventLog.ps1)

I have a test script where this works because I set the document.getElementByID, - table = document.getElementById("myTable"); - creating the html table myself and setting the ID. I'm not able to use the same function to grab the ID of the EventLog info to apply the same principle

Artefacts:

The working search function from Convert-toHTML-and-Search-Test.htm

```
#------------------------------------------------#
#       Convert to HTML and Search       #  
#------------------------------------------------#
#                    Version 1                            #

$TESTCSSbody = @"

  <h1>Type in a value from the table below to search</h1>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..." title="Type in a name">
  
  <table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:auto;">Hostname</th>
    <th style="width:auto;">DomainName</th>
    <th style="width:auto;">ServerRole</th>
    <th style="width:auto;">ServerDescription</th>
    <th style="width:auto;">MaintenanceWindow</th>
    <th style="width:auto;">PatchingStatus</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Server1</td>
    <td>Domain1</td>
    <td>Role</td>
    <td>Domain Controller</td>
    <td>MaintenanceW1</td>
    <td>Patched</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Server2</td>
    <td>Domain2</td>
    <td>Role</td>
    <td>Domain Controller</td>
    <td>MaintenanceW2</td>
    <td>Pending</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Server3</td>
    <td>Domain3</td>
    <td>Role</td>
    <td>Domain Controller</td>
    <td>MaintenanceW3</td>
    <td>Failed</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, ii;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:not(.header)");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        var found = false;
        for (ii = 0; ii < tds.length && !found; ii++) {
            if (tds[ii].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        tr[i].style.display = found?"":"none";
    }
}
</script>

<style>
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable { width: auto;  border: 1px solid #ddd; font-size: 18px;}
#myTable th, #myTable td { text-align: left; padding: 12px; }
#myTable tr {  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover { background-color: #c4c4c4;
}

 h1 { text-align: left; font-size: 20pt; font-family: Calibri; }
 h5, th { text-align: left; font-size: 14pt; font-family: Calibri; }
table { width: auto; font-family: Calibri; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888; border: thin ridge grey; }
th { background: black; color: white; max-width: 400px; padding: 5px 10px; }
td { font-size: 11pt; padding: 5px 20px; color: black; }
tr { background: #b8d1f3; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background: white; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #f1f1f1; }
tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

</style>
"@


#HTML Report info
$SEARCHTESTREPORT = "C:\htmlreports\ConvertToHTML-and-Search-Test.htm"
$SEARCHTESTREPORTtitle = "TESTING SEARCH FUNCTIONALITY"

ConvertTo-Html -Body $TESTCSSbody -Title $SEARCHTESTREPORTtitle |

#Output the HTML File to $HTMLREPORT
Out-File $SEARCHTESTREPORT
start $SEARCHTESTREPORT
```

Get-EventLog.ps1

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# This script produces the Windows Event Viewer in HTML #
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

#HTML Report info
$HTMLREPORT = "C:\Get-EventLog\eventlogreport.htm"
$HTMLREPORTtitle = "Event Log Report"

#Apply CSS Formatting
$CSSbody = @"
  
<h1>Event Viewer</h1>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..." title="Type in a name">

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, ii;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr:not(.header)");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        var found = false;
        for (ii = 0; ii < tds.length && !found; ii++) {
            if (tds[ii].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        tr[i].style.display = found?"":"none";
    }
}
</script>

<style>
#myInput {
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable { width: auto;  border: 1px solid #ddd; font-size: 18px;}
#myTable th, #myTable td { text-align: left; padding: 12px; }
#myTable tr {  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover { background-color: #c4c4c4;
}

h1 { text-align: left; font-size: 20pt; font-family: Calibri; }
h5, th { text-align: left; font-size: 11; font-family: Calibri; }
table { width: auto; font-family: Calibri; box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888; border: thin ridge grey; }
th { background: #00078A; color: white; max-width: 400px; padding: 5px 10px; }
td { font-size: 11pt; padding: 5px 20px; color: black; }
tr { background: #b8d1f3; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background: white; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #f1f1f1; }
tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

</style>
"@

#EntryTypes:
#-EntryType Error, FailureAudit, Information, SuccessAudit, Warning

#Lognames
#-Logname Application, Security, Setup, System

#$Begin = Get-Date -Date 01/01/2021 08:00:00
#$End = Get-Date -Date 04/02/2021 16:00:00
Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 100 |
Select -Property EventID,Source,MachineName,EntryType,Message,TimeGenerated,UserName |
ConvertTo-Html -Body $CSSbody -Title $HTMLREPORTtitle |

#Output the HTML File to $HTMLREPORT
Out-File $HTMLREPORT
start $HTMLREPORT
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how the Event Log table looks like same as you did with the previous working example?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Absolutely, let me remove any personally identifiable fields like the machine name and username! :P